# How to fix React Webpack-Dev-server complaint regarding bundle size?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server, hot-reload

Thank you for taking the time to read and possibly help with this issue. I am building a boilerplate react/express full-stack application. I have managed to get it going, however, I cannot fix this issue regarding webpack-dev-server complaining about the bundle size. This is currently a barebone application, and I am afraid that it will only get larger.

[image]
https://github.com/ducvtrann/pern-boilerplate - npm run start-dev to boot the app up

Thank you all!

Best,

Duc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change webpack mode from production to development and warnings will be gone.